# How do I get Eclipse internal browser to use edge and not IE browser widget?

Tags: eclipse, browser

I am using 2020-06 on Windows 10. When I open the internal browser view (WebBrowserView), it seems to be using the IE browser widget (when a popup asking to save or search is shown, a "search" opens an IE view). The documentation indicates it is possible to select from a subset of browsers that might be installed.

I tried setting the Windows > Preferences > WebBrowser internal to Chromium (edge was not a choice).  I set the Java system property -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType="edge".  Neither of those changed that IE is what pops up to ask about saving.

How do I configure this?

Answer (score 1):

"edge" was only made a valid value in Eclipse 4.19. You are using Eclipse 4.16.

Comment: Thanks, progress.  Window Preferences now has an Edge choice in 2021-06. Selecting with either internal or external radio button pushed does not affect the internal browser.  It still defaults to IE, though that is not my default system browser, and IE is no longer supported by Microsoft.  When I set org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType to edge, I get an exception that the internal browser cannot open.  There is an SWT.EDGE style choice, and snooping the source code indicates "edge" is the property value to use.  Do I need to configure something else so it can find what it needs to find?

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the Eclipse forum pointed me to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538991.  The answer (at least for now) seems to be to also install the WebView2 runtime.  With the property set, 2021-06 used the edge engine for the SWT browser widget.